# Classes not shown in iOS dynamic framework

Tags: ios

I have a dynamic framework (actually it's `NumericKeyboard` library on github but it supports Cocoapods only so I want to build a dynamic framework for personal use). If I use the framework on a newly test project, it works fine, all classes are shown:

[image]

But If I use it in my existing project, there's no classes at all:

[image]

Two frameworks are the same. So what can be the problem with my existing project here? I tried clean derived data, clean project,... without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just 5 minutes after ask the question, I found out that instead of build the framework with `Generic iOS Device`, I built it with `iPhone 7 Plus` device so it will show the classes only if I choose simulator.

So I placed the answer here in case there's someone has the same problem.